# onBitmapLoaded of Target object not called on first load

Tags: picasso

In my function :

```
public void getPointMarkerFromUrl(final String url, final OnBitmapDescriptorRetrievedListener listener) {
final int maxSize = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.icon_max_size);
Target t = new Target() {
  @Override
  public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    if (bitmap != null)
      listener.bitmapRetrieved(getBitmapDescriptorInCache(url, bitmap));
    else
      loadDefaultMarker(listener);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    loadDefaultMarker(listener);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
  }
};

Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .resize(maxSize, maxSize)
    .into(t);
}
```

The onBitmapLoaded() is never called the first time I load pictures. I've read some topic like https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/39 which recommand to use fetch(Target t) method (it seems to be a problem of weak reference...), but this function is not  available in the last release of picasso (2.3.2). I've only a fetch() method, but I cannot use into(mytarget) at the same time

Could you explain me how to use fetch() with a custom Target please ? Thank you.

Doc : http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fetch--

Comment: make sure to use okhttp 2.0.0, I encounter same issue when using Picasso 2.3.2 with Okhttp 1.6.0

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp
afaik, it is mandatory if you're using Picasso 2.3.2 to include okhttp (and okio) library. are you using eclipse or android studio ?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ. I've seen my gradle dependencies, I didn't see okhttp...
Picasso seems to work without it

Comment: @psv how did you implement below solution with the markers?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

As noted by the other respondents (@lukas and @mradzinski), Picasso only keeps a weak reference to the `Target` object. While you can store a strong reference `Target` in one of your classes, this can still be problematic if the `Target` references a `View` in any manner, since you'll effectively also be keeping a strong reference to that `View` as well (which is one of the things that Picasso explicitly helps you avoid).

If you are in this situation, I'd recommend tagging the `Target` to the `View`:

```
final ImageView imageView = ... // The view Picasso is loading an image into
final Target target = new Target{...};
imageView.setTag(target);
```

This approach has the benefit of letting Picasso handle everything for you. It will manage the `WeakReference` objects for each of your views - as soon as one is no longer needed, whatever `Target` processing the image will also be released, so you're not stuck with memory leaks due to long-lived targets, but your Target will last as long as its view is alive.

Comment: YES! I chose to create a parallel list of target (List<Target>) to keep all the target objects, but your solution is better. The target "will last as long as it's view is alive". Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an image view, how can I solve this problem then? When dealing with this kind of situations, the gc is your worse enemy

Comment: You can even store it in an ArrayList<Target> and it will work, just remember to clear that arraylist :-)

Comment: In onBitmapLoaded and onBitmapFailed, I am also doing imageView.setTag(null) after processing the bitmap. Is it not needed ?

Comment: Shouldn't we nullify the tag in `onBitmapLoaded` / `onBitmapFailed` ?

Comment: @tim687 I don't have a view either so i have nothing to tag my target to. I know this is old, but did you find a solution?

Answer (score 65):

Picasso does not hold a strong reference to the Target object, thus it's being garbage collected and `onBitmapLoaded` is not called.

The solution is quite simple, just make a strong reference to the `Target`.

```
public class MyClass {
   private Target mTarget = new Target() {...};

   public void getPointMarkerFromUrl(final String url, final OnBitmapDescriptorRetrievedListener listener) {

         Picasso.with(context)
         .load(url)
         .resize(maxSize, maxSize)
         .into(mTarget);
   }
}
```

Comment: Or make your `View` implement `Target`.

Comment: in the docs, it says you have to override `Object.equals(Object)` and `Object.hashCode()` methods. do you have a working sample?

Comment: where is it written ? I still have my problem even by making a strong reference to my Target().

Comment: I have now installed okHttp, it's a bit faster to load but I still have the same problem at the first launch. Any ideas ?

Comment: @psv: Did you get to solve picasso first launch issue? I have the same problem? If you have solved how did you solve it?

Comment: @TheDevMan, nope it's not solved. Workaround solution I used : Save each target object in an ArrayList to avoid garbage collection. It's "dirty" and reduce performances but I don't have any other solution.

Answer (score 27):

If I had ImageView I would simple make like this: imageView.setTag(target);

I use next solution for loading Bitmaps into notifications, so I need only bitmap.

So create Set witch will store Target objects and remove them on finish loading.

```
final Set<Target> protectedFromGarbageCollectorTargets = new HashSet<>();

private void loadBitmap(String url) {
   Target bitmapTarget = new BitmapTarget();
   protectedFromGarbageCollectorTargets.add(bitmapTarget);
   Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(bitmapTarget);
}

class BitmapTarget implements Target {

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
           
                    //handle bitmap
                    protectedFromGarbageCollectorTargets.remove(this);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
            protectedFromGarbageCollectorTargets.remove(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {
 
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is nEvent ?
   Target bitmapTarget = new BitmapTarget(nEvent);

Comment: @NimaAzhd you can ignore it.

Answer (score 13):

```
ImageView profile = new ImageView(context);
        Picasso.with(context).load(URL).into(profile, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {//You will get your bitmap here

                        Bitmap innerBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) profile.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    }
                }, 100);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
```

Comment: It's solved my problem too. i wanted use it with Notification. sometimes image was downloading with Target and sometimes not. but after using ImageView i was able to load images everytime

Comment: in my case, except all, this was the best solution!

Comment: @RaveeshGS notification builder  in android uses setLargeIcon(Bitmap) to set Image. I don't know how you use ImageView instead of setLargeIcon !?

Comment: @NimaAzhd they are using imageview to just download the bitmap. After downloading you can use it wherever you want.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered similar issue and holding reference to the target didn't helped at all so I used the following code which returns a Bitmap:

---

```
Bitmap bitmap = picasso.with(appContext).load(url).get();
```

---

**on the down side** -> there's no callback and you can't call this function on the main thread, you have to run this function on a
background thread as in the following example:

---

```
handlerThread = new HandlerThread(HANDLER_THREAD_NAME);
handlerThread.start();

Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = picasso.with(appContext).load(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                //do whatever you wanna do with the picture.
                //for me it was using my own cache
                imageCaching.cacheImage(imageId, bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

Another thing that works a whole lot better is just using **Glide!**

I needed to use both of them since the purpose of my project was to use 2 different image downloading api's to show an images gallery and to give the user the ability to choose which api to use.

I have to say, I was amazed by the results, Glide's api worked flawlessly in every aspect (Glide's target doesn't have weak reference) wile Picasso gave me hell (that was my first time using Glide, I usually used Picasso so far, seems like today it's gonna change ^^ ).

Comment: I've tried lots of solutions, on the first try using Glide it downloaded everything correctly

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution for those who aren't using a view. This helper method uses a list to temporarily store the target object until a result is returned so that it isn't gc'd:

```
private List<Target> targets = new ArrayList<>();

public void downloadBitmap(final Context context, final String url, final MyCallback callback) {
    Target target = new Target() {

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            targets.clear();
            callback.onSuccess(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
            targets.clear();
            callback.onFailure(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        }
    };
    targets.add(target);
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(target);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like @lukas said (and quoting), Picasso does not hold a strong reference to the Target object. To avoid garbage collection you must hold a strong reference to the object.

About fetch() method. It's pretty clear in the documentation that fetch() is not to be used with an ImageView nor a Target, it's just to "warm" up the cache and nothing else, so you're not going to be able to use it the way you want.

I recommend you holding a strong reference like @lukas explained, it should work. If not please open up a new issue on the GitHub page of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue but when I change the dependency as below mentioned, It works properly now.

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
```