# android - set layout background from url

Tags: android, url, layout, bitmap, background

I don't think it's duplicating 'cause all the answers I've found were made several years ago. So, I load bitmap from URL and then do it this way:

```
currentView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(result));
```

...where "result" is Bitmap.

But "BitmapDrawable" is deprecated and it doesn't work from API 22 or 21.
Are there some other way of converting Bitmap to Drawable or loading drawable from URL instead of Bitmap?

Comment: Why does it matter if the answers are from several years ago?

Comment: You can use `Picasso` to do this. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207716/add-background-image-to-android-listview-using-picasso

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get Image from url in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android)

Comment: @Pztar it does 'cause some methods weren't deprecated that time and are so now.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation tells you - don't use the deprecated

```
new BitmapDrawable(result)
```

Instead use the API 18 version

```
new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), result)
```

Assuming you're supporting API 18+, otherwise you need to handle both version depending on the runtime API.

Comment: I tried, it's not deprecated anymore but layout background picture on my Nexus 5 emulator is still invisible (background is gray instead despite default background color was black). so what can be the reason in this case?

Comment: Are you sure the bitmap has been downloaded and processed correctly? You can check the preview of the bitmap with the Android Studio debugger.

Comment: It's okay on my Samsung with 4.2.2. The problems are on only the highest APIs. (actually, some problems are on all the devices I run on, but that's another topic maybe :) )

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide to load image from URL, Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface.

Glide takes care of making scrolling any list of images as smooth as possible and also receive, resize and display remote image.

For more information refer [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Add below dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Eg project https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Eg usage:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

    Glide.with(this).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(imageView);
}
```

In the `load` method just pass the URL of the image and in `into` just pass the view, in you case currentview.
For your scenario:

```
Glide.with(this).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(currentView);
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( RelativeLayout cannot be cast into ImageView

Comment: Yes you cant. You have to supply imageView to Glide

Comment: But how to add it into layout itself, without imageView?

Comment: The question does not give much information. I dont know what layout you are talking about. Please update your question with more details.

Comment: currentView is a ListView item being formed inside ArrayAdapter. The layout that is being inflated is RelativeLayout

Comment: He wants to set the background on a layout.

Comment: In case you want to set background of Layout with Glide you need to use Glide Custom Target - eg. Bitmap. See the Glide docs https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets