# How to set LinearLayout background image with Fresco in code

Tags: android, fresco

Earlier, I thought that Fresco can be used as a complete replacement of Picasso.

For example, I can use Picasso to load a Bitmap and set it on **any** view using solution as suggested on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777471/3913366) SO answer.

Is this supported with Fresco?

To be more specific with my question, is it possible to set a loaded image using Fresco on any View, **without having to create a custom View**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure its possible. Use next code:

```
Uri imageUri = com.facebook.common.util.UriUtil.getUriForResourceId(imgResId);
// or if you use link: 
// Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(webLinkToTheImage);

ImageRequestBuilder builder = ImageRequestBuilder
            .newBuilderWithSource(imageUri)
            .setRequestPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .setLowestPermittedRequestLevel(ImageRequest.RequestLevel.FULL_FETCH);

    final DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> dataSource =
            Fresco.getImagePipeline().fetchDecodedImage(builder.build(), imageUri);

    try {
        dataSource.subscribe(new BaseBitmapDataSubscriber() {
            @Override
            public void onNewResultImpl(@Nullable Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (null != bitmap) {
                    //TODO use bitmap
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailureImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
                if (dataSource != null) {
                    dataSource.close();
                }
            }
        }, new MainThreadExecutor());
    } finally {
        if (dataSource != null) {
            dataSource.close();
        }
    }


public class MainThreadExecutor implements Executor {
    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void execute(@NonNull Runnable r) {
        handler.post(r);
    }
}
```