# How to load image from Picasso library and set it as wallpaper

Tags: java, android, picasso

I received a picture from the Internet with the Picasso Library.
Then I set it up on the wallpaper.
But after running on my mobile, I approached the Force close.
Please help me if you make a mistake in coding or please offer if suggested for work.

```
  Bitmap result= null;
    try {
        result = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("http://wallpaperswide.com/download/the_amazing_spider_man_2012_film-wallpaper-1600x900.jpg")
                .get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can you post your error log?

Comment: Try using MainActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: @Darush I tried it but it was still closed

Comment: Please suggest me a solution!

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777354/how-do-i-set-background-image-with-picasso-in-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you are inside MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Picasso.with(this).load("http://wallpaperswide.com/download/the_amazing_spider_man_2012_film-wallpaper-1600x900.jpg").into(new Target(){

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
                try {
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("TAG", "onBitmapLoaded: ");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
                Log.d("TAG", "FAILED");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading image failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Prepare Load");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Make sure:

- you use this import `import com.squareup.picasso.Target;` instead of `import java.lang.annotation.Target;`
- you give INTERNET permission and SET_WALLPAPER permission in your AndroidManifest.xml. 

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />`

Lastly:
 wait for the image to download then check your device home screen and voila!!!

Comment: @nima1382na I am checking it right now. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: Thank you my friend

Comment: @nima1382na change import java.lang.annotation.Target; to import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

Comment: this will make the error :
Error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: @nima1382na add import com.squareup.picasso.Target; at the top of your class just below package declaration. Look at the answer again and see what you have missed. I have tested it on my own phone and works perfectly. Let me know if you checked everything.

Comment: @nima1382na also make sure your internet is working.

Comment: thanks . but it did not wor . can you send me your source ? please

Comment: Please let me know if u find any issues

Comment: Thankful . Where did you send your source? :(

Comment: Can you sen me your source ?  :(

Comment: @nima1382na here it is: https://github.com/DarushDev/picasso-wallpaper-test

Comment: Woooow Thank you so much so much. It was a long time to follow this tutorial. And thank you

Comment: @nima1382na Your most welcome. If that solved your problem you can mark the answer as accepted. :D...All the best..

Comment: Photos are downloaded too late. Is this a normal problem? My internet speed is also good.

Comment: I think so.. .same thing with my internet connection...it takes about 30 seconds in my phone to download the photo and set it as wallpaper.

Comment: Oh . 30 seconds is too much to download a picture! Another way to download a photo faster?!

Comment: Checked on high speed Internet and took 7 seconds to load...so it depends on the internet connection and the server load...so u probably can't do anything about it...