# Picasso not loading bitmap into imageview with target

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to load an url into an ImageView but Target doesn't seem to work like what I found told me. Below is my code:

```
ImageView methodButton= (ImageView) View.inflate(context, R.layout.view_home_scroll_view_image, null);
setMethodPicture(sectionModel.getContent().get(0).getThumbnail(), methodButton);
methodsContainer.addView(methodButton);
```

and

```
private void setMethodPicture(final String methodPicture, final ImageView methodButton){
    methodButton.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(methodPicture)) {
        Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                methodButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                return methodPicture.equals(o);
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return methodPicture.hashCode();
            }
        };
        Picasso.with(context).load(methodPicture).into(target);
    }
}
```

This doesn't load the picture to the imageView, but when i do this,

```
ImageView methodButton= (ImageView) View.inflate(context, R.layout.view_home_scroll_view_image, null);
methodButton.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);
Picasso.with(context).load(sectionModel.getContent().get(0).getThumbnail()).into(methodButton);
methodsContainer.addView(methodButton);
```

it loads the picture.
I want to do the first one so I can change the Bitmap I get before I put it in the ImageView, like changing the width and height, but basing on the original dimensions.

Comment: any logs you got in your logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, Picasso holds a Weak Reference to the Target. The correct answer can be found here: [onBitmapLoaded of Target object not called on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180805/onbitmaploaded-of-target-object-not-called-on-first-load#answers)

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide instead, it provide predefine constrain options which you can add with it

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.