# onBitmapLoaded never called

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I've got an issue with `onBitmapLoaded`. The method is not called when it should be (it is called the second time i enter my view). Nevertheless i keep a reference to my target since i add it to an `arraylist`.

I don't understand why it's not working. 
Does someone have an idea ?

```
public void loadBitmap() {

    if(loadtarget == null) {
        loadtarget = new Target(){

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
                Log.d("Bitmap","On prepare load");
                targetList.remove(this);
                return;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Log.d("Bitmap","OKAY for :" + filename);
                targetList.remove(this);
                handleLoadedBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                Log.d("Bitmap","Error for :" + filename);
            }
        };
    }
    targetList.add(loadtarget);
    Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(loadtarget);
}
```

Comment: Where is loadtarget declared? As a class attribute?

Comment: Furthermore you have to override equals() and hashCode()-method. See JavaDoc: Objects implementing this class <strong>must</strong> have a working implementation of
 * {@link Object#equals(Object)} and {@link Object#hashCode()} for proper storage internally.

Comment: Yeah, loadtarget is a class attribute

Comment: From what i read, i thought i just had to override the three method of the target interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onBitmapLoaded of Target object not called on first load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180805/onbitmaploaded-of-target-object-not-called-on-first-load)

Answer (score 1):

If targetList and loadtarget are both local variables then they will be marked for GC collecting as soon as the method finishes.
Make sure targetList is a class variable so that its outlives the method.

Comment: targetList and loadTarget are both class variables

Comment: You should remove: `targetList.remove(this);` from `onPrepareLoad()` and add it to `onBitmapFailed()`

Comment: I noticed it after posting my question so i removed it but it didn't changed anything. onBitmapLoad is never called anyway.

Comment: I'm talking about `onPrepareLoad` not `onBitmapLoad`

Comment: I understood, i changed my code. targetList.remove(this) has been removed from onPrepareLoad() but nothing changed.

Comment: D/Bitmap: On prepare load  
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null  D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 696K, 7% free 27490K/29484K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 7% free 28291K/30324K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 82K, 7% free 29158K/31164K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 471K, 7% free 32040K/34104K, paused 20ms, total 20ms

Comment: Thank for taking time to answer me :)

Comment: New informations : i forgot to tell you that i was calling my loadBitmap in a loop. The function work fine if it is called once but seems to be in trouble when called in a loop.
Does this give new ideas ?

Comment: You are reusing loadtarget then, which might not be what Picasso expected. Try with removing this line: `if(loadtarget == null) {` and the closing `}` so you create a new one each time.

Answer (score 0):

I've find some kind of trick to solve my problem.

By replacing :
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(targetList.get(i));

With :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).transform(new Transformation() {

            @Override
            public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
                handleLoadedBitmap(source);
                return source;
            }
            @Override
            public String key() {
                return "";
            }
        }).into(imageView); // imageView is a fictive imageView allocated only for this operation
```

my code is working. I'm not sure that it's the best solution but it fixed my problem.