# I want get a bitmap use Picasso but fail

Tags: android, picasso

I am tried this code, but not getting the desired output.

```
 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mPicList.get(position)).into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        zoomImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        Logger.getInstance().v("qw", "ViewPagerAdapter.134.onBitmapLoaded.");           
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        Logger.getInstance().v("qw", "ViewPagerAdapter.139.onBitmapFailed.");       
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                        Logger.getInstance().v("qw", "ViewPagerAdapter.144.onPrepareLoad.");
                    }
                });
```

It always print log onPrepareLoad why????

Comment: Why shouldn't it call that method?

Comment: What is the issue you are exactly facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that nothing keeps a strong reference to the Target instance so it gets garbage collected. 
You can't just call new Target() { ... } because there aren't any strong references to it. You need to store it on a field in a view holder or implement it on a subclass of a view.

See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30681395/5476209

this guy explicitly managed garbage collection issue happening in library.

Comment: success with zoomImageView.setTag(mTarget);

Comment: no problem at all whenever you got any situation like this kindly go to that github library and at least check issues in library, your issue is already discussed there in picasso library. @dukemars

Comment: thanks,I have never use stackflow before,thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a reason for `new Target()...` but you can try to use something like this:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(mPicList.get(position)).into(zoomImageView);
```

If you are in a Fragment, use `getActivity()` instead of `this`.

Comment: thanks,but there is no Fragment,Only ViewPager Adapter

Comment: You can pass `context` to your adapter and use it instead of `this`