# Callback for picasso image loader

Tags: android

I am using Picasso library. I know that there is a call back method if i am loading a picture from a URL into an image view. But i don't want to load into an imageview. Instead, i want save it as a bitmap. so i used below code

```
 Bimap bmp=Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(urlString).get();
```

How can i get a callback method for this to know that my image is downloaded successfully using picasso?

Dont say that null check for bitmap object. It causes error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to listen for Picasso (Android) load complete events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548660/how-to-listen-for-picasso-android-load-complete-events)

Comment: No it is loading image in to image view. I want to get it as a bitmap. Please read my question again.

Comment: Was thinking about another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617505/picasso-load-image-into-target
It does what you want plus solves you problem that you might have

Answer (score 2):

if u want to get `Bitmap` using picasso you have to use a `Target`

```
    private Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
          //success
          Save_bitmap(bitmap);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
      }
}

private void Laod_Image() {
   Picasso.with(this).load("Your_url").into(target);
}
```

Comment: This seems like an answwer

Comment: @AtHulAntony if the answer helps mark it as correct...thankx

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [rafsanahmad007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42815342/4235666) look nice but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181629/4235666) also use onDestroy method to cancel the request.