# I can't load many images with Picasso (with target)

Tags: java, android, image, download, picasso

I have about 200 images in my web storage. When I try to download them with Picasso, I get only about 30 of them. I checked many cases and every time I get the different quantity of images and images are different too.
LogCat said that getPicassoImage() always called, but onBitmapLoaded() called only about 30 times and never called onBitmapFailed().

In LogCat I also saw (After first click - first warning and I can't get at least 1 image. This always on the first click):

> W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.A system to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
>
> W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '*path*' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

```
void getPicassoImage(final String imageName){
    Log.d("myLogs", "try to get "+ imageName);
    Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            /*Log.d("myLogs", "onBitmapLoaded");*/

            try {
                File file = new File(IMAGE_PATH + imageName);


                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                Log.d("myLogs", imageName + " image saved");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("myLogs", "Picasso error");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            Log.d("myLogs", "onBitmapFailed");
        }
    };

    /*Log.d("myLogs","Load from " + storageUrl + imageName);*/
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(storageUrl+imageName).into(target);

}
```

Comment: How much is the overall size of images ? i mean dimension of them.

Comment: @Smartiz only 20 mb. Images 50-300kb

Comment: Dimension !!! 200* 300 pixel for example

Comment: @Smartiz 250*375, 200*300, 500*600, 600*400

Comment: I guess the problem is with HEAP and the LRUCach system.
your heap become full so it cant load anymore, and it cause onBitmapLoaded dnt call again.

Comment: @Smartiz how I can fix it?

Comment: try this and see if it work :

Picasso  
    .with()
    .load()
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .into();

the memory policy should do the trick.

Comment: I solved it with http://stackoverflow.com/a/30681395/6567034
Cause of the problem is weak reference.