# setBackground() in onActivityResult is never called

Tags: android, picasso

In my app the user can pick a image from the gallery and set it to the background of a `RelativeLayout`. But the image is never immediately set as to the background in my onActivityResult() method as supposed to when I load the bitmap of the choosen picture with picasso to my view.

Here is a screenrecord video of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jABnheTV0IU

But when this method inside my RecyclerView Adapter is called the image is set as background to the RelativeLayout immediately:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        int position = getLayoutPosition();
        String path = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(App.IMAGE_URI,"");

        /*
        This put the current selected image from the gallery as background
         */
        if (position == 0 && !path.isEmpty()) {

            Picasso.with(context).load(path).centerCrop().resize(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight()).into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
```

**the onActivityResult in my MainActivity class.**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {


    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && data.getData() !=null) {

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString(App.IMAGE_URI, data.getData().toString()).apply();

        Picasso.with(this).load(data.getData()).centerCrop().resize(width, height).into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

            //this is never called or dosn't work
            relativeLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));


            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Just underneath here (if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && data.getData() !=null) {) add (Log.i("Running", "Running");) and in the Logcat Search type (Running)  -- do you see Running when you go back to the Main Activity?? if you dont then this is wrong (if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && data.getData() !=null)

Comment: @Tasos Yes "Running" appears in the logcat when I choose an image from gallary and it returns back.

Comment: then type picasso in the search -- any errors??

Comment: @Tasos No everything seems fine.. I think its the setbackground() method inside onBitmapLoaded, that dosn't update the background.. I don't think its picasso that the problem

Comment: Where is the recycler view? and where is startActivityForResult called?

Comment: @NickCardoso the solution below works! But startActivityForResult is called in the recyclerview's adapter for button indeks 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180805/onbitmaploaded-of-target-object-not-called-on-first-load) Picasso only keeps a weak reference to the `Target` object. Which mean that you need to make hard reference to it somewhere. Make `Target` as `MainActivity` class memeber. So call to load will look like so:

```
//Create Target right before it's needed
mTarget = new Target() {/*same as in your question*/};
Picasso.with(this).load(data.getData()).centerCrop().resize(width, height).into(mTarget);
```

Or you could declarate following inner class

```
private static ViewTarget implement Target {
    private View mView;
    public ViewTarget(View view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        mView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
    }
};
```

And use it like so:

```
mTarget = new ViewTarget(relativeLayout);
Picasso.with(this).load(data.getData()).centerCrop().resize(width, height).into(mTarget);
```

Comment: How would I load the Bitmap into my RelativeLayout.setbackground();?

Comment: Nice it worked! Could you give me a good explantion why this works and not the other?

Comment: Can't say precise but looks like for first case Picasso load image between GC calls so reference to `Target` survives. Actually I suggest you to update `onClick()` code in the same way to make it bullet proof.