# Picasso image is not loading on first run

Tags: android, picasso

I am using picasso to load image from a url. Since i needed bitmap for further processing, I am using Target() class for saving the bitmap. But picasso is not loading the image on the first run. But it loads at the time  when i goes to another activity and getting back to the picasso implemented activity. Why it is happening ? Any fixes? My code is below,

```
 Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(card.getExtras().getImageUrl()).into(new Target() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
                            Date now = new Date();
                            filename ="certificate_"+ formatter.format(now) + ".png";

                            File path=null;
                            if (getActivity().getExternalCacheDir()==null) {

                               path=getActivity().getCacheDir();
                            }
                            if(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir()!=null){
                                path=getActivity().getExternalCacheDir();
                            }
                           File  image=new  File(path+filename);
                            FileOutputStream fileOutPutStream = null;
                            try {
                                fileOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fileOutPutStream);

                                fileOutPutStream.flush();
                                fileOutPutStream.close();
                                Log.d("---REACHED","FILE SAVED--------------");
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                Crashlytics.logException(e);
                            }
```

Comment: Picasso.with(this)
   .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
   .into(imageView);

Comment: where is your set into imageview code?

Comment: You should try separating loading the image into Picasso from saving the image.

Comment: i will suggest you to use Glide

Answer (score 5):

Its a known issue, as picasso only keeps a week reference:

A solution to this issue would be to set the target as a `tag` to the view component you wish to set.

So your code will look like this:

```
Target target = new Target() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                           .....
// set the tag to the view
holder.imageView.setTag(target);

//set the target to picasso
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(card.getExtras().getImageUrl()).into(target);
```

A proper explanation for the same is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180805/onbitmaploaded-of-target-object-not-called-on-first-load) SO post!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for those who are wondering. The problem is due the weak reference of the target variable, so just define the Target globally, if you prefer as a Class variable and that fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for loading images.

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(carImageUrl).into(carImg);

where,
carImg is a id of Imageview in XML,
carImageUrl is a resource

Answer (score 0):

Try this function which I use:
And use `img.setTag(/*some other object than path of file or errId. But don't forget to add it before using this function*/)`. If you dont want to use it in same way then remove `if` conditions on checking `getTag()`.

```
public static void setImage(final Context context, final ImageView img, @DrawableRes final int defId,
                                @DrawableRes final int errId, final File file, Picasso.Priority priority) {
        if (null != img.getTag()) {
            if (null == img.getDrawable() || !(img.getTag() instanceof String && (img.getTag().equals(file.getAbsolutePath())))) {
                try {
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        Picasso.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                                .load(file)
                                .priority(priority)
                                .placeholder(defId)
                                .error(errId)
                                .fit()
                                .centerInside()
                                .tag(context)
                                .noFade()
                                .into(img, new Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess() {
                                        img.setTag(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError() {
                                        img.setTag(errId);
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        img.setImageResource(defId);
                        img.setTag(defId);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    img.setImageResource(defId);
                    img.setTag(defId);
                }
            }
        } else {
            img.setImageResource(defId);
            img.setTag(defId);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso image load for `ViewGroup (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, FrameLayout` etc

In my case following way works.

Need `HandlerThread` and `Handler` to load image.

Following example in **kotlin**. You may convert in **Java** as required.

```
val handlerThread = HandlerThread("ImageLoader")
handlerThread.start()

val handler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)
handler.post({
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
    try {
        bitmap = Picasso.with(this).load(iamgeUrl).get()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            runOnUiThread({
                imageView.background = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add placeholder property to picasso:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(imageData)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
       .resize(200,200)
       .into(mImageView)
```

Hope helpful for you!