# Picasso Android Bitmap load from URL does not work properly in service using target

Tags: android, bitmap, load, picasso

I try to get a bitmap from url using target.
Unfortunately I cannot get any bitmap from target.

```
Picasso.get().load(url_img+vo.getFile()).into(new Target(){
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Piccaso get");
        showMMS(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Piccaso Error : "+e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "pICCASO working");
    }
});
```

If I try to run picas I can see pICCASO working log at onPrepareLoad method.. but I cannot see Picasso get log at onBitmapLoaded method.

It seemed that it cannot get to onBitmapLoaded method.
However I cannot even see error log also.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Try the answer given here the problem is similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26918731/7425207

Comment: Thank you Sandu :) You save my time ~~~~~ :)